# XML files are downloading rather than viewing in Sharepoint

Tags: xml, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

We have two SharePoint 2013 sites. On one site, sitemap.xml is opened up in the browser. On another site, sitemap.xml is automatically downloaded rather than rendered in the browser.

Is there a setting that can be changed for this?

(fyi, this stackoverflow post does not resolve the issue: [SharePoint: render, rather than download, XML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4991258/sharepoint-render-rather-than-download-xml-file)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In central admin, Application Management > manage web applications, select your web app and go to it's settings.  In there, you should be a "Browser File Handling" section.  If it's set to strict, that's what's likely causing the file to download.  Set it to permissive and your problem may go away.  Keep in mind, that is a security feature.