# XML to HTML in .net

Tags: .net, xml, xml-parsing

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Advanced_IP_scanner>
    <row ip="10.10.1.4" status="1" name="remote003.domain.local" has_http="0" has_https="0" has_ftp="0" has_radmin_1="0" has_radmin_2="0" has_radmin_3="0" has_radmin_4="0">
        <share name="ADMIN$"/>
        <share name="C$"/>
        <share name="IPC$"/>
    </row>
    <row ip="10.10.1.12" status="1" name="remote005.domain.local" has_http="0" has_https="0" has_ftp="0" has_radmin_1="0" has_radmin_2="0" has_radmin_3="0" has_radmin_4="0">
        <share name="ADMIN$"/>
        <share name="C$"/>
        <share name="IPC$"/>
    </row>   
</Advanced_IP_scanner>
```

How can i convert above XML into simple HTML table to list all the rows and row headers so that I can show on my webpage.

Comment: Have you looked into using [XSLT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT)?

Comment: @Donut, you should post that as an answer.  Because that is exactly what they need to look at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of what a suitable stylesheet might look like. You'll have to adapt it of course depending on the HTML you actually want to produce.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="Advanced_IP_Scanner">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Ip Scanner Table</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>...</th>
              <th>...</th>
              ...
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
             <xsl:apply-templates/>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="row">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="@ip"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="@status"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="@has-http"/></td>
      ....
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

There are several XSLT processors available for .NET. The Microsoft one comes bundled with .NET, and only supports XSLT 1.0 (which is fine for a simple task like this, but runs out of steam on more complex transformations.) There are two independent processor that support XSLT 2.0 - my own Saxon product, which is well established and widely used, and a more recent arrival, XQSharp.

Answer (score 4):

You should use [XSLT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT), it's designed specifically for this task.
An example of what your code might look like is as follows (thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34093/how-to-apply-an-xslt-stylesheet-in-c/34095#34095) and [this page](http://www.csharpfriends.com/Articles/getArticle.aspx?articleID=63)):

```
XPathDocument myXPathDoc = new XPathDocument(myXmlFile) ;
XslCompiledTransform myXslTrans = new XslCompiledTransform();
myXslTrans.Load(myStyleSheet);
XmlTextWriter myWriter = new XmlTextWriter("result.html",null);
myXslTrans.Transform(myXPathDoc,null,myWriter);
```

Hope this helps. If you have further XSLT questions, don't hesitate to ask here.