# Sample code snippet help needed

Tags: c#, xml, visual-c++, mfc, ms-word

I want to know is it possible to convert XML with a set of instructions to MS word document in C#/VC++ ?
i.e if XML has line, then we should be able to draw line, if XML contains BOLD,bold the text in doc... 
If so Can i get set of sample examples?

Answer (score 1):

without reinventing the wheel, a possible way to achieve this task would be to use XML transformation i.e. XSLT.
You would then have to implement an XSLT engine into your C# / VC++ language.
Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34093/how-to-apply-an-xslt-stylesheet-in-c) for a topic about this.
Then you should find an XSLT stylesheet achieving this the conversion task. I just googled and found [this](http://www.tkachenko.com/blog/archives/000024.html)
Best regards