# Mass email individuals using xslt transformations and C#

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, xml-parsing

I need a way to read a list of names and email addresses from a database table using linq to xml.  After I generate the list to an xml string, I need a way to cycle through the list, by person(node), and apply xslt to the generated xml substring, generate html, and use the generated html to send to the person(s) as an email.  For example, I am thinking of the following xml layout: 
    `<persons>
        <person>
             <firstname>
             <middlename>
             <lastname>
             <emailaddress>
        </person>
    </persons>`

In this example, I would have to somehow traverse the xml like a for loop and visit each person node, get the node from `<person> .. </person>` and transform this one node at a time.

In certain situations, I will also need to print all of the letters that were generated as well.

How would I go about traversing the xml in this manner and transforming from the person node there after?  It seems like I would need the `<person> .. </person>` in string format.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: What have you tried already?  You will get better responses, if you post the code you have tried.

Comment: I described the requirements above.  Code wise, I am just starting out on this one.  Just trying to get a grip on the puzzle pieces I am staring at.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a Serializable Person class?  C# provides XML Serialization support.
So long as the raw text from the server is in a proper XML format, you could probably circumvent a lot of work by dumping it into an XML file and then relying on built in C# support.  Or by using LINQ to map the database to the class.

I'm certainly not familiar with LINQ, but [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43025/A-LINQ-Tutorial-Mapping-Tables-to-Objects) provides a pretty clear way to use LINQ to map a database to a class, which would provide you with a way to generate an XML File and use the built in Serializer, Deserializer, and XSL Transform to do whatever you like with the data.

```
XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Person[]));
people = (Person[])s.Deserialize(file); // Serialize is almost identical
file.close();
```

Will provide you an easy way to load in the XML into a C# Class from a file (or just LINQ to connect the SQL to a class).  You can use the built-in XLST support to take an XML File and transform it with an XSL Style Sheet:

```
XPathDocument x = new XPathDocument(xmlFile);
XslCompiledTransform xsl = new XslCompiledTransform();
xsl.Load(xslStyleSheet);
XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter("result.html", null);
xsl.Transform(x, null, writer);
```

Should take care of that -- From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34093/how-to-apply-an-xslt-stylesheet-in-c-sharp).
I'm sure there's some way you could do it with the raw string, but unless you *really* have to, why bother?

Comment: Can I do this using XML without using a file, I would rather do in memory, the handling of the xml-related items?

Comment: Actually this seems pretty clean.  It seems like with linq I get a list of person objects, serialize them one at a time, and perform xml activities and send email from there.

Comment: @user1790300 With a quick scan of the XslCompiledTransform class, the answer is "probably not."  However, I've done something similar to this -- I use a predefined email file (it was HTML) with markers like {first name} {last name} and {email address} -- something that wouldn't appear in regular text, and use a simple string replace to fill in the fields.  That approach would depend on how complex the Person class is and how many replaces you need, but I've used that approach with a Python file and a MySQL DB to generate mass emails.

Comment: First off, I have to say thanks for all of the answers so far, it has been a huge help.  Second, you are correct.  Ultimately, this is the task I have to achieve.  Parsing an html file was discussed as well, it just seemed like the xml approach was a little more straight forward and structured, no pun intended.