# How to return a list of LINQ to XML XElements without specyfying elements by name in SelectMany

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

Given an XML file like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root>
   <Policy id="832cbfc6-a451-4d77-a995-4ceb9d3bbe01" username ="DCassidy">     
      <Title>Test 1</Title>    
  </Policy>
  <Policy id="832cbfc6-a451-4d77-a995-4ceb9d3bbe02" userName ="DCassidy">
    <Title>Test 2</Title>
 </Policy>........and so on
```

Is it possible to use LINQ to XML to return all the 'Policy' elements and their containing elements without having to specify each element thing like:

```
var subset = doc.Elements("Policy").SelectMany(x => new[] { x.Element("Title").Value });
```

**I need to be able to dynamically add elements to the file, filter and return a subset.**

preferabbly, returning a collection of XElemets so that later I can call:

```
subset.CreateReader() on.
```

EDIT

**To be clearer.  I will want to return ALL Policy objects and their descendants based on the username attribute.  I the want to take that subset and use CreateReader() on it**.

Can someone help please?

Thanks

Comment: not just `doc.Elements()`?

Comment: you need some sort of solution like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13878590/parsing-inner-nodes-from-an-xml-using-linq/13878732#comment19115726_13878732

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Elements` overload that does not specify a name to get all the child elements.

```
var xml = @"
<Root>
   <Policy id='832cbfc6-a451-4d77-a995-4ceb9d3bbe01' username ='DCassidy'>     
      <Title>Test 1</Title>    
  </Policy>
  <Policy id='832cbfc6-a451-4d77-a995-4ceb9d3bbe02' userName ='DCassidy'>
    <Title>Test 2</Title>
 </Policy>
</Root>
";
var xElement = XElement.Parse(xml);
var subset = xElement.Elements("Policy").SelectMany(e => e.Elements());
```

The `subset` is an `IEnumerable<XElement>` whose contents are:

```
<Title>Test 1</Title> 
<Title>Test 2</Title>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`Elements()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.elements.aspx) method without specifying an element name to get all direct descendants:

`XDocument.Root.Elements()`

Answer (score 0):

It's not *really* clear what you mean, but perhaps:

```
var subset = doc.Elements("Policy").Descendants();
```

or

```
var subset = doc.Elements("Policy").DescendantsAndSelf();
```

This will get *all* descendants, not just direct ones. If you could be clearer about exactly what you're trying to achieve, that would help.