# How to render the XML Document in partial view with XSL?

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, xslt

Please note, 
I have an `XML` file which contains such information to display into User. And I have got the `XSL` file which contains the style information of the Content to display.

I wrote the following action in my controller to return the View which contains the `XML` file contents.

```
public ActionResult GetError()
{
  XmlDocument xdoc=GetXMLError();
  return View(xdoc);
}

[#GetError.cshtml]
@model System.Xml.XmlDocument
@MvcHtmlString.Create(Model.InnerXml).ToHtmlString()
```

But the Screen renders the xml what it has retrieved as a String not a HTML String. 
Which means its printing the xml what I sent.

I have also included the XSL file in Corresponding `View Folder.`

I have no clue of further proceedings.

Could anyone help me to resolve this out to Render the XML in specified style format?

Comment: Please read this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34093/how-to-apply-an-xslt-stylesheet-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the output. I thank @sundar G for his comment.

I changed the controllers as below,

```
public ActionResult GetError()
{
  XmlDocument xdoc=GetXMLError();
  XslCompiledTransform xsl = new XslCompiledTransform();
  xsl.Load(@"D:\Development\Test.xsl");
  XmlReader xReader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xdoc.InnerXml));
  StringBuilder stringBuilder=new StringBuilder();
  XmlWriter xWriter=XmlWriter.Create(stringBuilder);
  xsl.Transform(xReader, xWriter);
  return View(stringBuilder);
}
```

And in the view.

```
@model System.Text.StringBuilder
@MvcHtmlString.Create(Model.ToString())
```