# What is Styles.render equivalent for XSL/XSLT?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

In MVC4 you can render CSS stles by using

```
Styles.Render(path here)
```

Similarly scripts can be rendered by

```
Scripts.Render(path here)
```

But how do render XSL/XSLT stylesheets? Will Styles.Render do the trick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you do @Styles.Render or @Scripts.Render is because it references a bundle created somewhere in Global.asax, usually in the BundleConfig (look in your App_Start folder). They are created using the code

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/base/css").Include(
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.resizable.css"...
```

so then you can use them in your views as @Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css"). The framework actually creates a virtual file with the path "~/Content/themes/base/css" to enable this bundling technology.

I dont think the stylebundle can be used with xsl/xslt stylesheets, although I dont know for sure. Here are some relevant question to boot.

[How to apply an XSLT Stylesheet in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34093/how-to-apply-an-xslt-stylesheet-in-c-sharp)

or any of these really

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xslt+asp.net-mvc