# Transform XML Using XSLT in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xslt

I want to Transform xml using xslt and create new File instead of the set value xmlcontrol in Visual Studio. Below is My code. I need to create a new XML Transformed File Called tr.xml file in My root directory.

```
  System.Xml.XmlDocument doc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(Server.MapPath("hotels.xml"));
            System.Xml.Xsl.XslTransform trans = new
               System.Xml.Xsl.XslTransform();
            trans.Load(Server.MapPath("hotel.xsl"));
            Xml1.Document = doc;
            Xml1.Transform = trans;
```

Can Any one please help on this??/

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/34093/2400222

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to transform an input file to an output file with XSLT 1.0 in .NET 2.0 and later then you should use `XslCompiledTransform` and it is as easy as

```
XslCompiledTransform proc = new XslCompiledTransform();
proc.Load(Server.MapPath("hotels.xsl"));

proc.Transform(Server.MapPath("hotels.xml"), Server.MapPath("tr.xml"));
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0610k0w4.aspx for a detailed documentation of `XslCompiledTransform` and its possible inputs and outputs.