# XSLT move one xml tag value to other

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I have xml file with structure:

```
<root>
 <header>
  <filename>file.txt</filename>
 </header>
 <orders>
  <order>
    <name>foo bar</name>
  </order>
  <order>
    <name>foo bar</name>
  </order>
  ...
 </orders>
</root>
```

But i want to get rid of the  tag so the result xml should look like this:

```
<root>
 <header>
  <filename>file.txt</filename>
 </header>
 <orders>
  <order>
    <filename>file.txt</filename>
    <name>foo bar</name>
  </order>
  <order>
    <filename>file.txt</filename>
    <name>foo bar</name>
  </order>
  ...
 </orders>
</root>
```

In words i need to take  tag and put it into every  element.
What would be the simplest way doing this with XSLT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to create xslt stylesheet to transform your xml. The working example will look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:variable name="filename" select="header/filename"/>
    <xsl:element name="root">
        <xsl:for-each select="*">
            <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="local-name()='orders'">
                <xsl:element name="orders">
                    <xsl:for-each select="*">
                        <xsl:element name="order">
                            <xsl:element name="filename" >
                                <xsl:value-of select="$filename"/>
                            </xsl:element>
                            <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
                        </xsl:element>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You can find how to transform xml documnent here : [how to apply an xslt stylesheet in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34093/how-to-apply-an-xslt-stylesheet-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1):

You need to start the coding with the identity transformation template

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*| node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

plus a template for your `order` elements

```
<xsl:template match="order">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="../../header/filename | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```