# how to convert an xml file to a string while keeping the tags and populating some elements it contains with values?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

How to convert an xml file to a string while keeping the tags and populating some elements it contains with values?
Or is there a better way to get the desired result?
Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance!

VS2015 4.5

I have an xml file like this:

```
<OUTPUTS>
    <OUTPUT>
        <NAME len="10" type="String" />
        <ZERO len="2" type="Int" />
        <EMPTY len="5" type="String" />
        <RETURNCODE len="5" type="Int" />
    </OUTPUT>
</OUTPUTS>
```

my example values are (obviously nameValue and returnCodeValue ​​are variable from the program):

```
nameValue= "Daniel    ";
zeroValue="00";
emptyValue = "     ";
returnCodeValue = 00001;
```

I expect this string format:

```
<OUTPUTS><OUTPUT>nameValue(len10)+zeroValue(len2)+emptyValue(len5)+returnCodeValue(len5)</OUTPUT></OUTPUTS>
```

and so:

```
string result ="<OUTPUTS><OUTPUT>Daniel    00     00001</OUTPUT></OUTPUTS>";
```

My code is:

```
XDocument xml_data = XDocument.Load("EXAMPLE.xml");
foreach(XElement el in xml_data.Descendants())
{
    // more iterations to compose the string result 
}

// or         
foreach (XNode node in xml_data.DescendantNodes())
{
    // more iterations to compose the string result
}
```

But el and node contain the whole xml_data :

```
<OUTPUTS>
    <OUTPUT>
         <NAME len="10" type="String" />
         <ZERO len="2" type="Int" />
         <EMPTY len="5" type="String" />
         <RETURNCODE len="5" type="Int" />
    </OUTPUT>
</OUTPUTS>
```

I can not figure out how to extract OUTPUTS and OUTPUT tag (only the name and parentheses, not the elements they contain).

Comment: I don't understand your "expected" and "so:", but the modern way in .Net to work with xml is [`XDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xdocument?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: It's not clear whether the problem you're facing is in constructing the string that is the content of the `OUTPUT` element, or just putting that into an XML document afterwards. Those two tasks are separable, so it would be helpful if the question could just focus on the one that's causing you problems.

Comment: My problem is in constructing the string from xml file. The string must have this format: "<OUTPUTS><OUTPUT>Daniel 00 00001</OUTPUT></OUTPUTS>"; and so with tags e values because I have to invoke a third-party web service to which I have to pass this string in a request field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string name = "Daniel";
int zero = 0;
string empty = "";
int returnCode = 1;

var xml = XElement.Load("EXAMPLE.xml");
var output = xml.Element("OUTPUT");

int nameLen = (int)(output.Element("NAME").Attribute("len"));
int zeroLen = (int)(output.Element("ZERO").Attribute("len"));
int emptyLen = (int)(output.Element("EMPTY").Attribute("len"));
int returnCodeLen = (int)(output.Element("RETURNCODE").Attribute("len"));

string result =
    name.PadRight(nameLen) +
    zero.ToString("D" + zeroLen) +
    empty.PadRight(emptyLen) +
    returnCode.ToString("D" + returnCodeLen);

output.Value = result;
xml.Save("result.xml");
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this depending on where you want to take it.  You could read the file, and use regex and replace matches with those values.  Depending on the complexity you could use XSLT and transform it.
[How to apply an XSLT Stylesheet in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34093/how-to-apply-an-xslt-stylesheet-in-c-sharp)